# What's the meaning of Electrical Inches?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, terminology

I was reading a PCB design notes and guidelines from Xilinx for their 7 series FPGAs and came across this sentence:

> The capacitors should be placed as close as possible to the FPGA. Any
>   placement within two electrical inches of the device’s point of load
>   is acceptable.

What is the meaning of `electrical inches` ?

Comment: I would think the wires/traces length

Comment: I had to suspect inches honoring bends in your tracks. Not just a radius.

Comment: I wonder if this wire distance needs to be reduced according to the dielectric velocity factor?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

"Electrical inches" is shorthand for "inches of trace along which the electrons must flow". In other words, it's the length of the wires or traces, following any bends, not the straight-line distance.

Answer (score 22):

> An electrical inch is the actual distance along an electrical path.

Source: [UltraScale Architecture
PCB Design](https://forums.xilinx.com/xlnx/attachments/xlnx/MIG/10303/1/ug583-ultrascale-pcb-design.pdf) from xilinx.com

Footnote on page 19
Referred to as "Added footnote with **definition of electrical inch** to 0805 Ceramic Capacitor" in revision history (version 1.6).